# Angular dynamically load configuration for MSAL

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-ad-msal

I've followed this guide https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/configuration.md to dynamically load configuration using factory providers and APP_INITIALIZER.

I am retrieving the settings from a .Net Core api which is reading from appsettings.json.

All is working OK and logging into my application is working. However, when the browser refreshes after authenticating and http calls are made. The application fails to load with error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'settings')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'settings')
    at Object.MSALInstanceFactory [as useFactory] (:44340/main.js:5200)
    at Object.factory (:44340/vendor.js:88500)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (:44340/vendor.js:88411)
    at R3Injector.get (:44340/vendor.js:88232)
    at injectInjectorOnly (:44340/vendor.js:82160)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (:44340/vendor.js:82164)
    at Object.MsalService_Factory [as factory] (:44340/vendor.js:35264)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (:44340/vendor.js:88411)
    at R3Injector.get (:44340/vendor.js:88232)
    at injectInjectorOnly (:44340/vendor.js:82160)
    at resolvePromise (:44340/polyfills.js:10063)
    at resolvePromise (:44340/polyfills.js:10015)
    at :44340/polyfills.js:10125
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (:44340/polyfills.js:9664)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (:44340/vendor.js:105535)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (:44340/polyfills.js:9663)
    at Zone.runTask (:44340/polyfills.js:9432)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (:44340/polyfills.js:9834)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are refreshing the browser your code is accessing the value of "setting" properly before it's initialized. You have to ensure that the refresh property is initialized before accessing it's value. In the doc you shared you are using setting property in config.service.ts file. You need to initialize the property like this:

```
` private settings: any = {};`
```

Before accessing it's value you need to check whether it's null of undefined like this:

```
`if (this.setting && this.setting !== null) {`
`// you logic`
`}`
```